# Why adding cores slows down my java program after around 10 cores?

Tags: java, performance, scalability, multicore

My program uses fork/join as shown below to run thousands of tasks:

```
private static class Generator extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    final MyHelper mol;
    final static SatChecker satCheck = new SatChecker();

    public Generator(final MyHelper mol) {
        super();
        this.mol = mol;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        long count = 0;
        try {
            if (mol.isComplete(satCheck)) {
                count = 1;
            }
            ArrayList<MyHelper> molList = mol.extend();
            List<Generator> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final MyHelper child : molList) {
                tasks.add(new Generator(child)); 
            }
            for(final Generator task : invokeAll(tasks)) { 
                count += task.join(); 
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return count;           
    }
}
```

My program makes heavy use of a third party library for isComplete and extend methods. The extend method also uses a native library. As far as the MyHelper class is concerned, there is no shared variable or synchronization between the tasks.

I use the taskset command from linux to restrict the number of cores used by my application. I get the best speed by using around 10 cores (say around 60 seconds). It means that using more than 10 cores results in slowing down the application, such that 16 cores finishes in the same time as 6 cores (around 90 seconds).

I am more confused because the selected cores are 100% busy (except for garbage collection every now and then).
Does anyone know what could cause such a slow down? And where should I look to solve this problem?

PS: I have made also implementations in Scala/akka and using ThreadPoolExecutor, but with similar results (although slower than fork/join)

PPS: My guess is that down deep in MyHelper or SatCheck, someone crosses the memory barrier (poisoning the cache). But how can I find that and fix or go about it?

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way: You do have 10+ cores right?

Comment: Yes. I tested it on a machine with 16 cores.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an overload due to assigning threads/tasks to the different cores. Also, are you sure that your program is entirely parallelizable? Indeed, some program cannot always use 100% efficiently all the cpus available and the time taken to dispatch the tasks might slow down the program more than it helps it.

Comment: As I said, all the assigned cores are shown to be above 95% busy. Using visualvm I see that every now and then the cpu usage drops, which coincides with garbage collection. But this happens equally for all situations.

Comment: Please define "entirely parallelizable". Theoretically, all jobs are independent and each job creates around 10 more jobs (of course in the end, the jobs don't create any children), resulting in a sort of tree of jobs. Unfortunately the third party library is too big to just dive into (it is open source), so I cannot say anything about its parallelizability. In fact, I would appreciate any ideas how to check that, too.

Comment: My other suggestion would be that you might be doing either more jobs or some jobs several times when using more CPUs, can you check for that ?

Comment: why should it happen? My code is the same. Do you mean that the fork/join platform and JVM may do that?

Comment: I don't really know, but if you are doing the same with more CPUs, the time shouldn't grow, but decrease. Hence, it can mean either that you don't actually do the same (more runs or runs are longer) or that it is not entirely parallel = some thread wait for each other, they are not independent.

Comment: I added another comment at the end of my question. It might be some sort of cache poisoning, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use a threshold on the size of your `molList` (or `mol`) variable to avoid forking on too small sets of data.

I'd been playing a bit with fork/join just to understand framework and my first examples did not take the threshold into consideration. Obviously i got awful perfomances. Fixing a proper limit on size of problem did the trick.

Finding the right value for the threshold requires you spend a bit of time trying different values and see how performances changes.

So, put an `if` at the very beginning of the `compute` method like this:

```
@Override
protected Long compute() {
    if (mol.getSize() < THRESHOLD) //getSize or whatever gives you size of problem
         return noForkJoinCompute(mol); //noForkJoinCompute gives you count without FJ

    long count = 0;
    try {
        if (mol.isComplete(satCheck)) {
            count = 1;
        }
    ...
```